# Facebook Canvas application anchor tags are not working properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

I'm developing a Facebook canvas application in rails 3.1 and using the latest Facebook graph API.

In anchor tags, when I give the `href='/something'` it's working nice when I navigate in same browser tab. The link is pointing to my host URL like `host_url/something host_url` contains HTTP as well , but when I open this anchor in a new tab using right click of mouse and chose to open in new tab it open the URL `http://host_url/something` and not in Facebook canvas.

I also change the anchor href with `http://apps.facebook.com/my-app-name/something` when I click this link nothing is displayed and request is no coming to my host. When I open this URL in new browser tab it works fine.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong - if you're using relative links that's what will happen, because the app content is loaded in an iframe

Change your links to be absolute URLs including the apps.facebook.com/[namespace] prefix if you want them to always link to the canvas app when opened in a new window